# How do I attach a single-use block through a field?

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I am working on a project that has a lot of custom block types (about 35). They are complex and have a lot of fields. They are being used with Layout Builder so all the blocks that get created are mostly single-use and hidden. The block plugin that is applicable here is the `InlineBlock` class provided by Layout Builder.

I want to re-use some of these block types in a node field. This usage is identical to how paragraphs are used on a field. The main module I would turn to in this sort of situation is [block_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field). Unfortunately it does not work with `InlineBlock`s, I've [created an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field/issues/3191907) about this.

Is there a solution for this problem? Are there other patterns or techniques I'm missing? At this stage my only obvious solution is to convert these types to paragraphs which I know how to use in Layout Builder.

Answer (score 1):

The block_field module is designed to reference block plugins rather than block content. I think what you want here is an entity reference field with an inline entity form or entity browser.

It's likely block field has never been tested with layout_builder enabled (where the InlineBlock plugin comes from) so that's where this confusion is coming from!